# How to convert "double" to "datetime" between Excel and c#

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I have a c# program which needs to create an excel object, and do some operations, 
here are parts of my code:

```
// c# code:

workSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "=2012/9/20";       //asign "2012/9/20" to cell[1,1] in Excel
double d = workSheet.Cells[1, 1].value();   // by default, Excel will return 11.17
Debug.Print(d.ToString());                  //c#:  d = 11.1777777777778
```

so how to make the output become "2012/9/20" again?

I have tried some codes, but fail:

```
DateTime str = DateTime.FromOADate(d);     //c#: str = 1/10/1900 4:16:00 AM
DateTime str = new DateTime((long)d);      //c#: str = 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this:

First set the format in the cell:

```
 ws.Cells[1,1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

Then set value as DateTime:

```
workSheet.Cells[1, 1] =new DateTime(2012,9,20);
```

And to get value use the following:

```
double d = double.Parse(workSheet.Cells[1, 1].value());
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
```

Comment: workSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "2012-9-20";
DateTime dt = workSheet.Cells[1, 1].value();
//Debug.Print(dt.ToOADate());

Answer (score 3):

By typing is `=2012/9/20" you're telling Excel that this is a formula. 2012 divided by 9, divided by 20 equal 11.17777777778.

Try storing the date without the `=` sign.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it will report me with the following message: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'string'"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store a literal or preformatted value in an Excel cell, precede the value with a single quote `'`. For example, `workSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "'2012/9/20";`.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, your excel value is not a date. Drop the equal sign at the beginning.

Once you do that you will get a proper double value for your time (which can be converted via the OADate function). What your getting now is nonsense.