# C# converting number into time error

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am reading time from a excel file and this is my code to convert number into time

```
    string time = "1350";
     DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string timestring = dt.ToString("h:mm tt");
    Console.WriteLine(timestring);
    Console.Read();
```

The problem is that my code works fine for 4 digit numbers but some numbers are like 600, 900 etc which should be converted into 6:00 PM and 9:00 PM but my code throws an error. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Try adding 0 ahead of those numbers like 0600 ,0900 and  so on.

Comment: Why would 600 be 6:00 PM?  Wouldn't it be 6:00 AM?  If not, then how *would* you expect 6:00 AM to be expressed in your format?

Comment: mate it is 6AM not 6PM

Comment: More imporantly - what *exactly* do you mean by "from an excel file".  Are you reading an XLS or XLSX file?  Or a CSV? Or something else?  Usually one uses OADates when reading date and time from Excel.

Comment: See also: [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12561169/634824)

Comment: thanks Matt i have added padding and its working fine and i am just reading time from csv file and the format is like 1350,500,600,1900 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pad them with zeros prior to converting to `DateTime`.

```
string time = "600".PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Comment: getting this error The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Although your answer provides the solution, this will display the time as 6:00 AM . Is it possible to display it as PM or should we need to enter '1800' instead to achieve it.

Comment: It's not _my_ answer that writes 6:00 AM. My answer was just about changing 600 to 0600. And yes, of course you should enter 1800 to get a PM time.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below solution - yes ,i have tried this solution while importing data from excel

Double dateVal = Convert.ToDouble(mydatetime);

Date? dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dateVal);

string timestring = dt.ToString("h:mm tt");

Comment: 1) What's "Try" (not Ty)? Have you checked it yourself?
2) Why is it not edited and formatted?
3) How is it better than my earlier answer?

Comment: The OP didn't really provide enough details, but yes - OADates are usually the way you get dates out of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) which means the text has to exactly match the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) provided otherwise you get an error.  The format string you are using: HHmm [specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) a 24 hour time with leading zero for times earlier than noon.  A string like "600" is only three characters long so it doesn't match the four character format (HHmm) specified.

It sounds like you don't want a leading zero so you probably want "hmm" (12 hour format) or "Hmm" (twenty-four hour format) so you can parse strings that don't have a leading zero.  If you use Hmm you'll have to specify 6:00 pm as 1800.  If you use hmm you'll probably also need to use the tt format string so you can distinguish 600 am from 600 pm

Comment: "Hmm" and "hmm" will still require 4 digits to be parsed.